# Returning random images (Edited Sorry for that)

Tags: android, arrays, image, random

I am developing an android game in which i have to return random images from a class. 
its basically a tic tac toe game in which when a player taps then an image shown which is cross type image. I have 5 cross images having different colors and i want to show them randomly
The problem is when i tap on tic tac toe board then if for example green color cross image shown, then computer play its move but then if i make another move it changes the image for second move but it also change the color of the first one which is not required. Lemme clear again by example
i tap first green image cross shown
i tap second orange color cross shown (but with the second tap the color of the first green image also changes and goes to yellow)

here is my code

```
public enum Player {
CROSS, CIRCLE, EMPTY;

public int Image() {
    switch(this) {
        case CROSS :
            int[] p = {R.drawable.kii, R.drawable.kiitwo, R.drawable.qq, R.drawable.qqq, R.drawable.qqqqq};
            Random random= new Random();
            int rndInt = random.nextInt(p.length);
             int resID = p[rndInt];
            return resID;

        case CIRCLE :
            int[] pp = {R.drawable.cclefive, R.drawable.ciclee, R.drawable.cicleefour, R.drawable.cicleetwo, R.drawable.ciclethree};
            Random randomm= new Random();
            int rndIntt = randomm.nextInt(pp.length);
            int resIDd = pp[rndIntt];
            return resIDd;
        default : 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

}

and here i am calling the player class

```
@Override
public void onBoardUpdated(Player[][] board) {
    dismissToast();

    for (int i = 0; i < mCells.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mCells[0].length; ++j) {
            Player boardPlayer = board[i][j];
            int colorResource = boardPlayer == Player.CROSS ? android.R.color.transparent : android.R.color.transparent;
            mCells[i][j].setBackgroundColor(colorResource);
            mCells[i][j].setImageResource(board[i][j].Image());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to call onTouch then you have to do it like this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if(fuelcount<1)
{
call();


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not allow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotatree);
         alarmclock.setAnimation(shake);
         alarmclock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Play, Fuel Tank is Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: But would that simple method will work same like overrided function ? i.e will it be able to handle ontouch event

Comment: do you want something on touch or something else?

Comment: Yes i want ontouch
lemme clear there is tic tac toe game and fuel bar is 10
lets suppose i played 10 times now fuel bar is 0 (decreases one by one on every game) 
now i want that when fuel bar is 0 the tic tac toe game cannot be played i.e when i touch any where in the screen it says fuel bar empty and user had to wait 10 seconds
so basically i need to call ontouch event but only when fuel bar is 0

Comment: Ok lemme try this one

Comment: try and tell if you any problem

Comment: Sir can you help me on another problem? i cannot ask another question as iam a beginner here and stack overflow dont allow me 2nd question

Comment: That's not true I think you can ask another question . Also upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not a good idea to dispatch events manually. I would improve design by creating

```
interface FuelListener{
   void onOutOfFuel(Event e);
}
```